# How do I apply SUM() aggregation function to many columns at once?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a common table expression aliased as `table` that I created with Big Query Standard SQL. `table` has many columns that I want to sum up into a single row using a `GROUP BY` aggregation.

I have tried this query, which returns the error

> `*` can only be used in the COUNT(*)

```
SELECT "all" as problem_type, SUM(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY problem_type
```

I am trying to avoid doing this for n columns:

```
SELECT "all" as problem_type, SUM(Value_1), SUM(Value_2), .... SUM(Value_N) 
FROM table
GROUP BY problem_type
```

Is anyone able to help with an efficient query to solve this task?

Comment: Give us some sample data and the desired result

Comment: I originally had an image of an example table, but my reputation was high enough to post . Mikhail's answer was helpful in getting what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the only option I can suggest you (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT problem_type, key, SUM(CAST(value AS INT64)) AS sum_value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{}"]', ''))) kv,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
WHERE NOT key = 'problem_type'
GROUP BY problem_type, key
```

you can test, play with above using sample / dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 problem_type, 1 value_1, 2 value_2, 3 value_3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 4, 5, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 7, 8, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 14, 15, 16 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 17, 18, 19 
)
SELECT problem_type, key, SUM(CAST(value AS INT64)) AS sum_value
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{}"]', ''))) kv,
UNNEST([STRUCT(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)] AS key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
WHERE NOT key = 'problem_type'
GROUP BY problem_type, key
```

with result

```
Row problem_type    key         sum_value    
1   1               value_1     12   
2   1               value_2     15   
3   1               value_3     18   
4   2               value_1     31   
5   2               value_2     33   
6   2               value_3     35
```

so, as you can see instead of what you asked originally - which is something like below

```
Row problem_type    value_1    value_2    value_3 
1   1               12         15         18     
2   2               31         33         35
```

But I think this is reasonable alternative especially if number of such columns big enough to waste time and typing all columns explicitly